# Encrypting a single file with password and keyfile

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I am a fan of TrueCrypt and I guess it's the best encryption tool available. As far as I understand, TrueCrypt created encrypted containers which acts a place to store files.

I would like to encrypt a **single file**. Preferably with a password and a special key file (like in TrueCrypt).

It would be great (but not mandatory) if the file doesn't require any third party software to encrypt and decrypt, in the sense that I provide the password and key to the file directly.

Comment: what OS? And no you can't get around using a third party software. A file can't encrypt itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the openssl command line utility, works on all OSs.

check http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/12/12/simple-file-encryption-with-openssl/ and http://www.dslreports.com/shownews/Encrypt-files-quickly-with-OpenSSL-87586 for examples.

Answer (score 5):

Use [AxCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/axcrypt/).

> I would like to encrypt a single file. Preferably with a password

AxCrypt only encrypts single files. You can encrypt multiple files at once, but they are each encrypted separately (with the same password if you wish to do so).

> ...and a special key file (like in TrueCrypt).

AxCrypt can also generate key files.

> It would be great (but not mandatory) if the file doesn't require any
>   third party software to encrypt and decrypt, in the sense that I
>   provide the password and key to the file directly.

AxCrypt gives you the option to create a self-extracting *.exe* file instead of a typical encrypted file. The self-extracting *.exe* file will not need AxCrypt to be installed in order to decrypt, but it will obviously still require the password or key file to decrypt.