# Looking for an open source program to encrypt individual files

Tags: encryption, dropbox, onedrive, google-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encrypting a single file with password and keyfile](https://superuser.com/questions/231868/encrypting-a-single-file-with-password-and-keyfile)

I really like truecrypt, but the only thing that I don't like about it is that there is no option (that I can see anyhow) that lets me encrypt individual files.

What I want to do is use the SkyDrive application so I can drop files in a certain folder and have them automatically sync to the cloud, but I certainly don't want to let them sync unencrypted. But if I use TrueCrypt to do it, I'm forced to make a large container to store stuff in, and that's cumbersome at best.

Is there a program out there, preferably free, that will let me encrypt stuff sorta like EFS does for NTFS, but doesn't break the encryption when I move it off an NTFS volume?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using two steps each time you want to edit a file, grab a copy of GnuPG from http://gnupg.org or your favourite distro's mirror and you can encrypt any one file any time you like with the "-c" option (using a password).

It supports all the best major algorithms and works on both Windows and Linux (and Android for that matter).